# Interpreting Dusart's sum of prime approximation

Tags: prime-numbers

I am trying to plot Dusart's sum of prime approximation [ref 1]:

[image]

However I'm not getting the correct sum but very large incorrect numbers. Some things come to mind:

1) I'm entering the acsii version into c as 
(N*N*0.5*(log(N)+log(log(N))-(3/2)+1)
where the log is natural log.

2) I've not understood correctly that lnln*n* is log(log(N))

3) just lost!

Furthermore using Landau's approximation for the same thing:

$$S_n =\frac 12  n^2 \, \log(n)  + O\left(n^2 \log(\log(n))\right)$$

I cannot interpret the big O correctly as once again using ascii to compute in c the big O as follows, (N*N*(log(log(N))) ).

I get very large incorrect numbers for the big O that should be smaller than the main term.

[ref 1] ON THE ASYMPTOTIC EXPANSION OF THE SUM OF THE FIRST n PRIMES
Nilotpal Kanti Sinha November 9, 2010

https://ia801009.us.archive.org/13/items/arxiv-1011.1667/1011.1667.pdf

Comment: $o(1)$ is not $1$. $o(1)$ means something which tends to zero as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: @Wojowu okay thank you for pointing that out also looking carefully it appears to be little o not Big O. In any case even with o(1) removed it still does not work.

Comment: For $n=10^6$ I got $S_n\approx 7.47\times 10^{12}\;$ with the Dusart's formula, $S_n\approx 6.9\times 10^{12}$ with Landau's formula, while the actual value is $S_n=7\,472\,966\,967\,499$

Comment: @onepound We can't guess what you're doing wrong if you tell us nothing about what you are seeing... "I'm not getting a sum" is a description devoid of any content.

Comment: @Erick Wong seeing? I'. talking about the values the ascii formula is producing in c. I think that is quite clear and confirmed by the answer below. Therefore this should not have been voted down otherwise nobody especially non mathematical people will benefit.

Comment: @onepound Wrong. You didn’t indicate what values of $n$ you tried, and you didn’t give a single example of what you consider to be a “large incorrect number”.  That is a completely subjective assessment and you gave us no basis on which to understand what you consider to be a large error in approximation.  You didn’t even give us enough information to tell whether your error is due to integer overflow, because one ascii string does not make an implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C you may have an error in using 3/2 which will always be treated as integer division. This may lead to some error.

Using the expression

```
N*N*0.5*( log(N) + log(log(N)) - (3.0f/2.0f)  )
```

for $N = 1, \ldots, 100$

I get the following relative errors between the estimates and the actual values for $\sum_{r\le n} p_r$

[image]

E.g. for $n=100$, the estimate I get is 23161.749 for the actual value of 24133.